# Copy date from table to another table in a different db

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Cant work out what I'm doing wrong here, I'm trying to copy the data from table to another in a different db. My Sql is

```
SELECT * INTO [dbo].[dbname].table FROM thistable
```

Should be really simple but it won't work.

Comment: are the 2 DBS in the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
SELECT * INTO [dbname].[dbo].table FROM thistable
```

Cheers!

Comment: doh got [dbo] and the table name the wrong way around, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use fully qualified name on both database names then it will work.

```
SELECT * 

INTO <databasename>.<schema>.<table>

FROM <databasename>.<schema>.<table>;
```